# cocos2d-x how to use CCFadeOUT

Tags: ios, cocos2d-x, fadeout

I just want to know how to use this simple class, I've checked the reference and googled for examples with no luck. Please help me it gets me crazy.

here's the code i try to use:

```
CCFadeOut *fade = CCFadeOut::create(10);
fade->startWithTarget(someLabelWithText);
```

thanks

Comment: If you use cocos2d for iOS than isn't it with objective-c? CCFadeOut *fadeOut = [CCFadeOut actionWithDuration:10]; [someSprite runAction:fadeOut];

Comment: it's cocos2d-x but yeah I had to use the runAction method of the label, thanks a lot

Comment: what does it mean label? CCLabelTTF or what?

Comment: yep, sorry for not being clear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
CCFadeOut *fade = CCFadeOut::create(10.f);
someLabelWithText->runAction(fade);//
```